# How to send HTTPS Post request along with JSON object in java?

Tags: java, json, post, https

I want to send JSON Data to an application using HTTPS connection from java code. please guide me.

`import java.net.URL;
import java.io.*;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class JavaHttpsExample
{

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String httpsURL = "https://your.https.url.here/";
    URL myUrl = new URL(httpsURL);
    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection)myUrl.openConnection();
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    }

    br.close();
}
```

}`